# Are printable tech trees with building and upgrade cost/time to build available?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does anybody have a link to a printable tech tree for StarCraft 2, especially with building and upgrade costs/time to build? PDF format would be best, but any sort of reference that is publicly available would be handy.

Found these ones, but they don't have costs/time to build: (Based on the in-game tech tree) http://starcraft.incgamers.com/wiki/Terran_Tech_Tree

Comment: Also found: http://sc2armory.com/game/terran/tech_tree which is nice, but not in a good format to print out.

Comment: http://sc2armory.com/game/zerg/tech_tree and http://sc2armory.com/game/protoss/tech_tree also. I really like the combination of units and research shown there, would be great to have that all in one printable format...

Comment: http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/2780/sc2techtree.pdf: printable pdf but not very nice looking.

Comment: Why not just take a screenshot in game or from the SC2 site and print the ss? would atleast keep it nice

Comment: Thanks thethinman, that bare-bones one is actually pretty useful. I could pencil in the building/unit costs next to each one. Was a better print in landscape than portrait mode, and would be better again with each race on a separate page.

Comment: I would like to note that the ghost academy does not require a factory to be built, as is illustrated in @thethinman's PDF.  It does however, require a factory to build Nukes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to three printable tech tree images. There isn't any data associated with the pictures but hopefully they're identifiable and you can add whatever you need yourself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJKJ0.jpg

Comment: That is useful, thanks - I'll take a look at how well they print + including data, probably from the SC2armory or Liqupedia sites.